# loop variable in param

Tags: php

i'm having an error "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object"

on this line `$stmt->bind_param("ss", $influencer_id, $campaign_id);`

```
  public function getCouponDetailsMenu($influencer_id)
  {

    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id, campaign_id, campaign_name, status, type_of_campaign, client, brand, influencers, max_coupons, distributed_coupons, expired_coupons, claimed_coupons, coupon_expiry, campaign_start_date, campaign_end_date FROM tbl_campaign WHERE influencers=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$influencer_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $campaign_id, $campaign_name, $status, $type_of_campaign, $client, $brand, $influencers, $max_coupons, $distributed_coupons, $expired_coupons, $claimed_coupons, $coupon_expiry, $campaign_start_date, $campaign_end_date);
    $campaigns = array();
    while($stmt->fetch()) 
    {

      $temp['id']=$id;
      $temp['campaign_id'] = $campaign_id;
      $temp['campaign_name'] = $campaign_name;
      $temp['status']=$status;
      $temp['type_of_campaign']=$type_of_campaign;
      $temp['client']=$client;
      $temp['brand']=$brand;
      $temp['influencers']=$influencers;
      $temp['max_coupons']=$max_coupons;
      $temp['distributed_coupons']=$distributed_coupons;
      $temp['expired_coupons']=$expired_coupons;
      $temp['claimed_coupons']=$claimed_coupons;
      $temp['coupon_expiry']=$coupon_expiry;
      $temp['campaign_start_date']=$campaign_start_date;
      $temp['campaign_end_date']=$campaign_end_date;
      $temp['logo'] = $this->getDistributedEmail($influencer_id, $campaign_id);
      array_push($campaigns, $temp);
    }
  $stmt->close();
  return $campaigns;

  }

}

//Method to get distributed email
public function getDistributedEmail($influencer_id, $campaign_id)
{
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT user_email_address FROM tbl_coupons WHERE influencer_id=? and campaign_id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $influencer_id, $campaign_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($eadd);
    $email = array();
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
    $temp = $eadd;
    array_push($email, $temp);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    return $email;
}
```

Comment: Why the *javascript` tag ?

Comment: Possibly your `$stmt` is not an object and it may be `false` by prepare statement.

Comment: i've checked it many times it is correct..

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($stmt);`?

Comment: result of var_dump "bool(false) "

Answer (score 0):

It seems `$stmt` not an object. try to debug it by using `var_dump($stmt);` right after your prepare-call.

I think it occurred because  the sql statement sent to it is not valid in the current DB.

> sounds like the prepare-call fails (don't know why) and so it returns
>   `false - false is not an object`, so you can't call `bind_param()` on
>   that.
>
> If the database server successfully prepares the statement, PDO::prepare() returns a PDOStatement object. If the database server cannot successfully prepare the statement, PDO::prepare() returns FALSE or emits PDOException (depending on error handling).

Comment: result of var_dump "bool(false) "

Comment: So I think you should check do you connect to database exactly? and after that check your sql statement. Does it work true (without error and return at least on record )?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by putting

$stmt->store_result();

after

$temp['campaign_end_date']=$campaign_end_date;